# Tap gesture for MapKit

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, mapkit, core-location

Currently I have a map that has several `Annotations`.

For the `Annotations` I have

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView){
     // Do your annotation click work
}
```

Is it possible to do this for tapping the Map only and not the `Annotation` and how can I do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `ViewWillAppear` method :

```
let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:"triggerTouchAction:")
mapView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
```

And Whatever information you want to show just add code in following method :

```
func triggerTouchAction(gestureReconizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
      //Add alert to show it works
}
```

Hope it going to help you to resolve issue.