# How to Move to 2nd Viewcontroller when we tap on mapView using MKMapView in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapview, pushviewcontroller

In first viewcontroller i have mapview and below textfields containerview.. if i tap on mapview how to go second viewcontroller?

if i tap anywhere in map i should go to 2nd VC:

[FirstVC.. if i tap on map i have to go to 2ndVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3blLT.jpg)

2ndVC design:

[2ndVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckeqN.jpg)

for both viewcontrollers i am using `MKMapView`

for that i have written code from this answer [Tap gesture for MapKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41075945/tap-gesture-for-mapkit)

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:"triggerTouchAction:")
     mapView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)

}
func triggerTouchAction(gestureReconizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
         //Add alert to show it works
       print("print working")
       let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewZoomAddressViewController") as! NewZoomAddressViewController;

      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true);
   }
```

**then it hits below error**

> RegistrationViewController triggerTouchAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f999e81a400
>    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Project.RegistrationViewController1 triggerTouchAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f999e81a400'

How to design like above mentioned screens, please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41075945/tap-gesture-for-mapkit

Comment: @aiwiguna, i have just edited.. the post with that answer.. it says `unrecognized selector sent to instance` .. please one take a look at my edited post with your suggested answer.. where i am wron

Comment: its because old selector code, in current swift it will be like this https://pastebin.com/pya8vhZ9

Comment: @aiwiguna, thank you sooo much worked

Comment: @aiwiguna you didn't post answer.. if u posted the answer then i can accept

Comment: i post the answer, you can accept it @swiftPhone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UITapGestureRecognizer like this

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(triggerTouchAction(_:)))
         mapView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)

}
@objc func triggerTouchAction(gestureReconizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
         //Add alert to show it works
       print("print working")
       let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewZoomAddressViewController") as! NewZoomAddressViewController;

      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true);
   }
```