# swift mapView and a button . I am unable to get any touch events from the mapKit

Tags: swift, mkmapview

I have a tableviewController and it uses a custom cell class for it's data.
The custom cell has a Mapview and a button.
I was able to connect the button to an event like this

```
class MyTVCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
var placeButtonAction : (() -> ())?
var mapViewAction : (() -> ())?
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var placeButton: UIButton!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    self.deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(placeButtonSelected(_:)),for: .touchUpInside)

// This is where it fails as it does not recognize touchUpInside
    self.mapView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(mapViewSelected()),for: .touchUpInside)
  }

@IBAction func placeButtonSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
    placeButtonAction?()
  }

func mapViewSelected(){
    mapViewAction?()
  }
```

Any events that I can insert in this line?

```
self.mapView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(mapViewSelected()),for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: Use a gesture recognizer.

Comment: You mean use a method in MKMapViewDelegate? However which one? I want an event when someone taps in the mapview? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate

Comment: I saw a comment here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41075945/tap-gesture-for-mapkit

Comment: So what's the deal after I submitted a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the tap position over the map as a geographic location, the following should do the job.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(mapTapped))
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        mapView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        mapView.delegate = self
    }
    
    @objc func mapTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let tapPoint = sender.location(in: mapView)
        let geoPoint = mapView.convert(tapPoint, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
        print(geoPoint)
    }
}
```